# Ubuntu Server : Nginx https instead of http

Tags: nginx

I have a ubuntu server 12.04.

I installed on it NginX for a rails app. Then, I set a CNAME call dev.mydomain.fr on its IP.

But when I try to go on this website, I have nothing and have "https://dev.mydomain.fr" instead of "http://dev.mydomain.fr"

When I try to parse the site with curl on the server "curl http://dev.mydomain.fr", I have the good page.

Comment: can you post your `server{}` block?

Comment: Scuse... I resolved the problème 'just a cahcee problem...'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If somebody get some trubble with this !
Try to empty the cache of your browser !